# Finding column number in CSV with python

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv

I am using python builtin csv package and I need to have a 'smarter' way of finding a specific column, and its index.

Currently I manually count the column number but my files keep changing column numbers and cant count column numbers anymore.

This is my code so far

```
import csv
url_column_index = ""

#the column title i need is url

p = open('my-great-file.csv') 
csv_f = csv.reader(p)
   for row in csv_f: 
      if row[3] == 'url':
      # set url_column_index
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `csv.DictReader` instead.

Answer (score 0):

please look at python document
https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html

```
>>> import csv
>>> with open('names.csv') as csvfile:
...     reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
...     for row in reader:
...         print(row['first_name'], row['last_name'])
...
Baked Beans
Lovely Spam
Wonderful Spam
```